# How to write a sql query returning the count of data from a table that meet requirements

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, where-clause

I have a table with ID and City as columns.  I want to write a sql query that will return ID and count(ID) as columns where City = City and ID = ID.

I have this so far:

```
select N.ID, count(N.ID) as OpenCities
into #new2 
from #new N
where ...
```

the where is the part I'm having trouble with.  Please help.  Thank you.

Sample Data:

```
ID   |   City
=============
1      New York
1      Chicago
2      New Jersey
2      Chicago
2      Chicago
3      Miami
3      Miami
3      Miami
3      Miami
3      Tuscon
```

What I want returned:

```
ID   |   OpenCities
===================
2        2
3        4
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: What does it mean "where City = City and ID = ID"?

Comment: I want the count of all the instances in the table where ID's are equal and so are Cities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grouping by `id` and `city` and only getting results with a count more than 1.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    count(1)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID, City
HAVING count(1) > 1
```

Comment: what is the 1 in count(1)?

Comment: It's the same as `count(*)`. It provides a count of the records regardless of `NULL`.